# Check for a specific character in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check for a specific character in a element?

```
<div>N0180/RIB</div>
<div>N0180918</div>
<div>N0180</div>

**(I want to target <div>N0180</div> this element)**
```

I tried to use ***`:contains("N0180")`*** and `.substring` method. But it is target all three elements.

Answer (score 3):

As per `:contains()` Doc:

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.

You can rather use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** for more specific comparison :

```
$('div').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim() === "N0180";
})
```

Comment: But function can be independent...method can not be..And that is the reason they have used the term `method` in the docs.. _the .filter() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements._

Answer (score 0):

For exact match use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim() == "N0180";
})
```

Note: For case-insensitive search convert the values to same cases using [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [`.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').each(function() {

  if ($(this).text() === 'N0180') {

    $(this).addClass('red')

  }


})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>N0180/RIB</div>
<div>N0180918</div>
<div>N0180</div>
```

You can get the `.text()` of div and compare to your text